# How are these convolutions possible given the stride and input size?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, dcgan

[image]

Input size is 1 x 128 x 128. Stride used throughout is 2.
Looking at the generator, from left to right, the input/output dimensions with every layer should be:

1. 128/63
2. 63/30
3. 30/14
4. 14/6
5. 6/2
6. ?/?
7. ?/?

Is it possible that the diagram is incorrect?

Comment: I believe it's 128->64 and so on. 2 ** 7 = 128, so you can do downsampling 7 times max. Which paper this figure from?

Comment: Privacy-Protective-GAN for Face De-identification (Wu, Lang, Ying). The thing is that a stride of 2 =/= divide in half, its the difference of the input dimensionality and the convolutional filter dimensionality which gets divided by the stride (then + 1).
So for the first layer, its floor((128-4)/2) + 1 = 63.